# Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick section 18.3 (integration of general measurable functions) question 30

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

I'm struggling with question 30 in section 18.3, copied below:

> Let X be the disjoint union of the measurable sets $\{X_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$. For a measurable function $f$ on X, characterize the integrability of $f$ on X in terms of the integrability and the integral of $f$ over the $X_n$'s.

I wasn't entirely sure how to interpret the question itself to begin with, this is how my professor rephrased the question to me

> The problem asks one to prove the following statement:
> In order that f is integrable on X it is necessary and sufficient that f is integrable on $X_n$ for all n, and $\sum^\infty_{n=1} |\int_{X_n} f_n d\mu| < \infty$

I have spent around 2 weeks banging my head against the wall trying to figure out how to do this and the more I scrape my proofs and start from scratch the more nonsensical they get so I think it's time for me to ask for help. This is the latest set of nonsense I've written:

> Let f be integrable on $X_n \forall n$. $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ with $X_i \cap X_j = \varnothing$ if $i \neq j$. Then by countable additivity over domains of integration it follows that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n} f d\mu = \int_{X} f d\mu$ so f is integrable.
>
> Conversely, let f be integrable on X. Then $|f|$ is also integrable on X.
>
> $\sum_{n=1}^\infty | \int_{X_n} f d\mu | = \sum_{n=1}^\infty | \int_{X_n} f^+ d\mu - \int_{X_n} f^- d\mu| \leq \sum_{n=1}^\infty [ \int_{X_n} f^+ d\mu + \int_{X_n} f^- d\mu] = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n} |f| d\mu = \int_{X} |f| d\mu < \infty$. Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty | \int_{X_n} f d\mu | < \infty$ \
>
> As before, $X = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_n$ with $X_i \cap X_j = \varnothing$ if $i \neq j$. Then by countable additivity over domains of integration it follows that $\int_{X} f d\mu = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{X_n} f d\mu$ so f is integrable on  $X_n \forall n$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer seems to be okay except for the first part. I would like to rephrase it as follows.

$$
\int |f|d\mu<\infty~iff~\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{X_n} |f|d\mu<\infty
$$

Now, we can prove it as follows.

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int_{X_n} |f|d\mu=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\int|f|\mathbf1_{X_n}d\mu=\\
\int \lim_{n\to\infty}|f|\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbf1_{X_i}d\mu=\int|f|\lim_n\mathbf1_{\bigcup_{i=1}^n X_n}d\mu=\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty
$$

Here, we use Monotone convergence theorem in the second equality, that is, $0\le g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n|f|\mathbf1_{X_i}\uparrow |f|\mathbf1_X$.